# Detecting broken pipe in Solaris send() call

Tags: c, sockets, solaris, broken-pipe

In solaris how to detect broken socket in send() call? i dont want to use signal.
i tried SO_NOSIGPIPE and MSG_NOSIGNAL but both are not available in Solaris and my program is getting killed with "broken pipe" error.

Is there any way to detect broken pipe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `sigaction()` to specifically ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal:

```
struct sigaction act;

act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, NULL);
```

...then `send()` will return -1 with `errno` set to `EPIPE`.

Comment: Thanks. Its similar to signal() function. i dont want to use signal() or sigaction().

Comment: Well, that is your only option if you do not want to suffer `SIGPIPE` on Solaris.  You can use the third parameter of `sigaction()` to save the previous disposition of the signal, and restore it after calling `send()` if you need to.

Comment: MSG_NOSIGNAL was just standardized by POSIX in their latest revision so it is likely that Solaris will adopt this at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in Solaris you have only limited options. AFAIK, sigaction suggested by caf appears to be the best solution.